# Google Maps API Endpoint for Reporting Errors?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am attempting to complete a task which requires a number of addresses to be reported to Google Maps for having inaccurate location coordinates.

While this can be done manually by reporting each location via maps.google.com, I was hoping a more automated way exists.

Is anyone aware of a Google Maps API call which allows me to send reports, or any other similar service to accomplish my task?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you're doing that, but you can simply check the result returned by the api and create your own report. I don't think the API will do that for you.